# Create .img of current of android setup

Tags: usb, flashtool

I have an android setup (certain apps, wifi settings, backgrounds, etc) that I'd like to get on 20 other devices.  I have physical and root access to all devices.  I have been using a [USB burner tool](http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/04/16/how-to-firmware-upgrade-amlogic-s802/) to update the software that a device shipped with to a more recent version of the software that the hardware manufacture released.

My question is, give a current setup of android, how can I create a .img file that I can burn onto other devices using the USB burner tool?

Comment: Have you looked into making a Nandroid backup with a tool like Clockworkmod Recovery?

Comment: Simply put: Do a Nandroid backup and restore it on all devices. But be aware: You may need to change hostnames, Device IDs etc. as they are included in the backup.